# Changing XML style resource in Android with Java

Tags: java, android, android-xml, android-styles

I have most of my elements in the UI referencing a style resource for font size, size, color, etc. Would it be possible to change the value of one of these `<item>`'s dynamically? I was hoping to get the physical dimensions of the screen and change the size so that it takes up roughly the same percentage of the screen with different screen sizes.
`<item name="android:textSize">12dp</item>` would go to `<item name="android:textSize">15dp</item>`

Comment: You can't change `resources` at runtime.

Comment: :( Is there something similar to weight with text size? I have the bounding size of the text view scaling great. I just need the text to actually scale with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you mean that you want to apply styles for different screen sizes.

look this: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

that will help you.

**Edit:** After a few researches, I've found a possible answer so far.

```
// declaring resources
int mHeight;
int mWidth;
/* I am considering a TextView, if you want,
 * you can apply it for any widget you like. */
TextView mTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.your_textview_id);

/* right. now we want to get the screen dimensions. */
Display mDisplay = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
mHeight = mDisplay.getHeight();
mWidth = mDisplay.getWidth();

/* now we have the values that needed.
 * the next thing to do is mathematical operation.
 * do this as you wish. the thing I do is obtain a
 * value that the mHeight is subtracted by mWidth and divided by 2. */
float mTextSize = (float) (mHeight - mWidth) / 2;

// apply it as text size of the TextView.
mTextView.setTextSize(mTextSize);
```

Comment: Sort of, it needs to be more dependent on the physical size (inches and mm) and not the dpi or aspect ratio. values/styles-small/text_size.xml (normal, large, xlarge) is what I am looking for?

Comment: It isn't as dynamic as I would like, but it works. Using a text size style that inherits from a common base style works nicely.

Comment: yeah, still we don't know to find a way to change the style dynamically by java codes, we have to use this method.

Comment: it is possible to set it for a textview, I've updated my answer.